Why is $e^n$ written $\exp(n)$?
Since $e^n$ is a more compact notation, and to be fair gives the reader more information, why then would one choose to write $\exp(n)$? What is the history of these notations?

Presumably to emphasize that it is a function.

@JoséCarlosSantos It's quite clearly a different question as it asks when one notation may be better than another.

@MathematicsStudent1122 The question is different, but the answers answer this question.

If you have a large expression in the exponent, the $\exp$ notation is easier to read. For instance, $\exp\left(|x+1|^\frac{x^2+1}{x^2-1} - 25\right)$ versus $e^{|x+1|^\frac{x^2+1}{x^2-1} - 25}$.

Yeah, that makes a lot of sense. Thank you!

$exp(x)$ was also easier to type on a typewriter than an exponent. Such things take a lot of time to disappear.
